# Equivalent to F#’s Seq.scan() method in Python?

Tags: python, f#, functional-programming

Is there a function like a F#'s `Seq.scan()` in Python?

I want to do some `cumsum()` or `cumproduct()` kind of things without looping.

Comment: `scan(operator.add, [1,2,3,4]) == [1,3,6,10]`. Not `map` or `reduce`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignacio's solution is almost right I think, but requires a operator of type ('a -> 'a -> 'a) and doesn't yield the first element.

```
def scan(f, state, it):
  for x in it:
    state = f(state, x)
    yield state
# test
>>> snoc = lambda xs,x: xs+[x]
>>> list(scan(snoc, [], 'abcd'))
[['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
>>> list(scan(operator.add, 0, [1,2,3]))
[1,3,6]
```

Specifically, the type of `Seq.scan` is

```
('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> seq<'T> -> seq<'State>
```

The default approach in Python is to write a `scan` with the type

```
('State -> 'State -> 'State) -> seq<'State> -> seq<'State>
```

This comes from the way that Python specifies `reduce`, which has the same type by default.

Comment: +1, but I'd yield before applying the first reduction. I don't know about F#' scan, but Haskell's does return the initial state as first element (which makes a lot of sense): scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
 # [0,1,3,6].

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

```
def scan(op, seq):
  it = iter(seq)
  result = next(it)
  for val in it:
    result = op(result, val)
    yield result
```

Comment: You should do one `yield result` before the loop, otherwise the result will be missing the first element.

Comment: Yeah, the MS docs were a bit vague as to what `Seq.scan<>() did`.

Comment: Thnx. Actually, F#'s Seq.scan() requires another parameter as an initial state(result).. Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about doing cumsum/cumprod operations, then you should look at numpy's super efficient [cumsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [cumprod](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) operations on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

you can use accumulate function get the same functionality which is python equivalent to scan:

```
from itertools import accumulate
nums=[1,2,3,4,5]
nums_added=list(accumulate(nums,lambda x,y:x+y))
print(nums_added)

#prints
# [1,3,6,10,15]
```

You can also use rx (reactive extension) to use scan operator.
It's a external library. so you need to install it before using it.
with rx you can do something like this:

```
from rx import  from_, operators as op
nums=[1,2,3,4,5]
source=from_(nums).pipe(op.scan(lambda x,y:x+y))
source.subscribe(lambda num:print(num)

#prints
#1
#3
#6
#10
#15
```

rx can do much more than this it allows you to do reactive programming.
To learn more visit this: http://reactivex.io

Comment: you can use `operator.sum` instead of `lambda x,y: x+y`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions would use `reduce` rather than `map`.

See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html for more info

Comment: reduce() returns the final value only.. not the list of the intermediate values. So i can get sum(), but not cumsum()

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure but give this a try

```
map(function, iterable, ...)¶
```

More on this on [docs.python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)