# Is it possible to call a function (not a built in function) inside a list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension, nested

Say we have a list:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and we have created a function called add():

```
def add():
  sum = 0
  result = 0
  for e in X:
    sum = sum + e
    return sum
add()
```

which runs through a list of numbers X, adding the next element in the list to the previous sum. So for each element X[i], we have:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```

Now, what if I want to put these results in a list again, by making use of a list comprehension. Is it possible to call a function such as add() within a list comprehension,
given that it is possible to apply built in functions inside list comprehensions?

I have tried the following:

```
L = [add() for e in X]
print L
```

which gives

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

instead of

```
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45]
```

Why am I getting NoneType values in this list?

Comment: I'm not sure how a single `add()` call has produced multiple values.

Comment: Something is wrong here - the `add()` function returns only one value and it should be the same each time (because `X` is not being modified). Are you sure you have `return` and not `print` in `add()`?

Comment: Your `for` loop returns on the first iteration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to F#’s Seq.scan() method in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805624/equivalent-to-f-s-seq-scan-method-in-python)

Comment: I get `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` instead; are you certain you are using the right `add()` function?

Comment: This is due to where I am returning 'sum'. Perhaps this wasn't clear in the question - but I want multiple values, each representing the sum of the current value X[i] plus any previous values which have already been added up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Haskell scanl in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14423794/1157100)

Comment: I am using the add() function which I have defined above.

Comment: BTW why do (did) you think that only builtin functions can be used?

Comment: I assumed this -  because I have not yet succeeded in nesting a function I have written. I'm interested in investigating why this is.

Comment: @200_success - I don't see how my question could be a duplicate of ' Equivalent of Haskell scanl in python', as it does not look like the function is being called inside the list comprehension in the example given. (I certainly would not have been able to find it through searching for it)

Comment: You want to accomplish the same thing — just explained in wildly different vocabulary.

Comment: probably best to avoid using `sum` as a variable name

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with `yield` to keep with your original format:

```
    X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    def add():
      sum = 0
      for e in X:
        sum = sum + e
        yield sum

    L = [value for value in add()]
    print L
```

Comment: `L = [value for value in add()]` would seem clearer in this context.

Comment: I also suggest changing `add()` to take `X` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to call functions inside list comprehensions. Your example is fine - it's the `add()` function that is to be blamed.
What you need is make the `add()` function receive an argument - the list to sum.

```
def add(elements):
    sum = 0
    for el in elements:
        sum += el
    return sum
```

This way, the list comprehension would look like this:

```
L = [add(X[:i+1]) for i in xrange(len(X))]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
L = [add(X[:1]), add(X[:2]), ..., add(X[:8])]
```

Which turns out to be a list of prefix sums - the thing you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach won't work, because your `add()` is stateless.  You need something that maintains state between different invocations of `add()`, otherwise `add()` will always produce the same output.

One solution to accomplish what you want is [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).  See [Equivalent of Haskell scanl in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423794/equivalent-of-haskell-scanl-in-python) for a discussion.

Other answers here have suggested using a list comprehension that involves a `range()`.  While that would work, it would also be inefficient, as an O(n^2) algorithm that recomputes the cumulative sums from scratch for each entry.

Comment: Are you saying that the list X would be fixed for this reason? Can you clarify what you mean here?

Comment: I'm saying that every time you call `add()`, it will produce the same output, because it takes no parameters, performs no mutation, and is generally unstateful. klasske's suggestion to change `return` to `yield` works, because generators do keep state.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
produce a list that adds each item to the previous item
this list [1,2,3,4] will produce this list [1,3,6,10]
"""

def accumulate(my_list, previous = 0):
    for i in my_list:
        previous += i
        yield previous

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
new_list = []
new_list = [i for i in accumulate(x)]
print x   
print new_list
```

produces this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to call any function in list comprehension.

Also note that in Python 2.x you cannot have `print` in list comprehension because [`print` is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141098/list-comprehension-why-is-this-a-syntax-error) (in Python 2).

To your example - it could look like this, using an `add()` function that works with shared state (the `s` variable):

```
s = 0   # better not use name 'sum' as it is already a builtin function
def add(i):
    global s
    s += i
    return s
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print [add(i) for i in X]
# prints [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36]
# but beware the global shared state! for example when called again:
print [add(i) for i in X]
# prints [37, 39, 42, 46, 51, 57, 64, 72]
```

See other answers how to do it without that shared state so you don't get different results when you forget to set `s = 0`.